# Iterate whole XML file using TinyXML

Tags: c++, xml, tinyxml

I have some XML file's but there is one problem. My XML "tree" doesn't have one look. I mean once it can look like:

```
<one>
 <two>
  <three></three>
 </two>
 <four>
  <five>
   <six></six>
  </five>
  <seven></seven>
 </four>
</one>
```

But second time it can looks different.
Is there the way with TinyXML to iterate whole file and cout like:

three: text

six: text

seven: text

I saw examples like "I have to search element by his name", but if I don't know the name, what's the solution?

I'm asking, because I have already wrote program that do that, but only goes like NextSiblingElement() and goes like first child, first child, and when it goes to "last child of parent" then it checks if that child has a brother and then it stops. So imagine that on example: it goes from "one" to "two" from "two" to "three" "three hasn't child, so it checks if it has brother. No? then stops and doesn't go to four, five etc. Where is my mistake?

```
TiXmlNode* element = doc.FirstChildElement();
TiXmlNode* element_parent = doc.FirstChildElement();
element = element_parent;

while (element != NULL) {
    std::cout << element->Value() << std::endl;

    if (element->FirstChildElement() == NULL) {
        element = element->NextSibling();
    }
    else {
        element = element->FirstChildElement();
    }

    if (element == NULL) {
        element = element_parent->NextSibling();
        element_parent = element_parent->NextSibling();
    }
}
```

Comment: _"... but if I don't know the name ..."_ Well, what are you trying to lookup then? Specific content? A particular structure? Specific attributes? Regarding the code you have post a [MCVE] in your question please, that reproduces your actual problem.

Comment: It means, I want to write a program that iterate whole XML file and put it on screen like parsed. I know pugixml can do that, but I want to check if TInyXML have possibility to do that aswell.

Comment: I don't see a reason why that couldn't be done with `tinyxml`. You maybe need kind of recursion or a stack like structure, to go back to nodes parsed earlier, and proceed with the siblings.

Comment: Exactly, i did put my example code, probably there is stupid mistake that i don't see. Remember there can't be like "Next element("five")" because we are not sure if exactly "five" element exist. Maybe it's called "nine" and program won't work now.

Comment: As mentioned, you need a stack like structure to remember nodes parsed earlier. The XML is  a tree like structure, so a simple flat loop won't work.

Comment: Okey, thank you @TheDude for help; now I see my logically mistake. It was very helpful.